# Creating poi-ooxml-schemas.jar with only classes for xwpf

Tags: java, android, apache-poi

may I know how to recompile

poi-ooxml-schemas.jar

with only

> 11448 org.openxmlformats.schemas.wordprocessingml.x2006.main
>     9217 org.openxmlformats.schemas.wordprocessingml.x2006.main.impl

I keep getting this error when I try to compile in android ADT bundle.

> 

```
trouble writing output: Too many methods: 66024; max is 65536. By package:
    13 java.lang
     1 java.lang.reflect
     5 java.util
     1 javax.xml.namespace
    66 org.apache.xmlbeans
    19 org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.values
     1 org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.xb.xmlschema
  2500 org.openxmlformats.schemas.drawingml.x2006.chart
  1430 org.openxmlformats.schemas.drawingml.x2006.chart.impl
  8767 org.openxmlformats.schemas.drawingml.x2006.main
  5258 org.openxmlformats.schemas.drawingml.x2006.main.impl
    86 org.openxmlformats.schemas.drawingml.x2006.picture
    33 org.openxmlformats.schemas.drawingml.x2006.picture.impl
   745 org.openxmlformats.schemas.drawingml.x2006.spreadsheetDrawing
   417 org.openxmlformats.schemas.drawingml.x2006.spreadsheetDrawing.impl
   230 org.openxmlformats.schemas.drawingml.x2006.wordprocessingDrawing
   164 org.openxmlformats.schemas.drawingml.x2006.wordprocessingDrawing.impl
   298 org.openxmlformats.schemas.officeDocument.x2006.customProperties
   256 org.openxmlformats.schemas.officeDocument.x2006.customProperties.impl
   617 org.openxmlformats.schemas.officeDocument.x2006.docPropsVTypes
   596 org.openxmlformats.schemas.officeDocument.x2006.docPropsVTypes.impl
   285 org.openxmlformats.schemas.officeDocument.x2006.extendedProperties
   196 org.openxmlformats.schemas.officeDocument.x2006.extendedProperties.impl
    23 org.openxmlformats.schemas.officeDocument.x2006.math
    24 org.openxmlformats.schemas.officeDocument.x2006.relationships
     2 org.openxmlformats.schemas.officeDocument.x2006.relationships.impl
  2076 org.openxmlformats.schemas.presentationml.x2006.main
  1224 org.openxmlformats.schemas.presentationml.x2006.main.impl
     1 org.openxmlformats.schemas.schemaLibrary.x2006.main
  7271 org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main
  4556 org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.impl
 11448 org.openxmlformats.schemas.wordprocessingml.x2006.main
  9217 org.openxmlformats.schemas.wordprocessingml.x2006.main.impl
     4 schemaorg_apache_xmlbeans.system.sE130CAA0A01A7CDE5A2B4FEB8B311707
  1170 schemasMicrosoftComOfficeExcel
  1223 schemasMicrosoftComOfficeExcel.impl
   285 schemasMicrosoftComOfficeOffice
   124 schemasMicrosoftComOfficeOffice.impl
     2 schemasMicrosoftComOfficePowerpoint
     3 schemasMicrosoftComOfficeWord
  2858 schemasMicrosoftComVml
  2529 schemasMicrosoftComVml.impl
[2013-04-27 10:20:02 - TestProject] Conversion to Dalvik format failed with error 2
```

I'm only using XWPF and manage to scale down to the classes I need from apache-poi.

but I am still facing the same "Too many methods"

> 1. I can't seem to find the source for the OOXML CT.. classes, where do they come from?
>
> The OOXML support in Apache POI is built on top of the file format XML
>   Schemas, as compiled into Java using XMLBeans. Currently, the
>   compilation is done with XMLBeans 2.3, for maximum compatibility with
>   installations. (You can use the resulting classes on the XMLBeans 2.3
>   runtime, or any later version of XMLBeans. If you are currently using
>   XMLBeans 2.2 or earlier, you will unfortunately have to upgrade, but
>   this isn't common any more).
>
> All of the org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006 CT...
>   classes are auto-generated by XMLBeans. The resulting generated Java
>   goes in the ooxml-schemas-src jar, and the compiled version into the
>   ooxml-schemas jar.
>
> The full ooxml-schemas jar is distributed with Apache POI, along with
>   the cut-down poi-ooxml-schemas jar containing just the common parts.
>   The source jar isn't normally distributed with POI. It is, however,
>   available from Maven Central - ask your favourite Maven mirror for the
>   ooxml-schemas-src jar. Alternately, if you download the POI source
>   distribution (or checkout from SVN) and build, Ant will automatically
>   download the specification XML Schema, and compile it for you to
>   generate the source and binary ooxml-schemas jars.

on apache website it says the above, I am not good with maven or ant. May I know if it is possible to create a poi-ooxml-schemas.jar with only the class I need for xwpf

Comment: Since a jar is just a zip file with a certain structure + metadata, can you not just delete the unwanted parts (eg spreadsheetml) from the zip?

Comment: I did but I want to do it properly.. Could there be some dependence?

Comment: Word won't depend on Spreadsheet, unless you have embedded a .xlsx file inside your .docx. It will depend on the common parts, metadata parts etc

Comment: Did you solve this? I faced the same problem and don't know which files can be removed.

Comment: Never did. I can't be performed because Android JDK does not support @Annotation.